# Los JButtons no ocupan todo el ancho del JPanel con GridBagLayout, Como lo soluciono?

Tags: java, java-swing, layout

Tengo un problema y es que cuando cargo los botones con los datos de la BD SQLite al agregarlos al panel con un While que recorre la BD no me los agrega en forma de lista vertical y tampoco los ensancha al tamaño del JPanel que los contiene, Apesar de que pongo lo necesario.. Alguien puede ayudarme? Si es así, Gracias de antemano..

He aquí el While:

```
public void cargarBtnCustomers(){
    try{
        Connection miConexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:customers_1.db");
    Statement miStatement = miConexion.createStatement();
    ResultSet miResultSet = miStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM customers_1");

    while(miResultSet.next()){
            //pnlIns.add(new JButton(new PersonAction(new Person(miResultSet.getString("name"), miResultSet.getString("identification")))).setBackground(Color.yellow));
            Person p = new Person(miResultSet.getString("name"),
            miResultSet.getString("ruc"), miResultSet.getString("repLegal"),
            miResultSet.getString("nombreContactoEmpresa"), miResultSet.getString("correoContactoEmpresa"),
            miResultSet.getString("numeroContacto"), miResultSet.getString("cedulaRepLegal"),
            miResultSet.getString("avisoOperaciones"), miResultSet.getString("nit"),
            miResultSet.getString("noContribuyenteMuniPa"), miResultSet.getString("contraMuniPa"),
            miResultSet.getString("obligacionFiscal"));
            // create a PersonAction with the recently created person as parameter
            PersonAction pa = new PersonAction(p);
            // create the JButton passing the PersonAction as parameter
            myBtn jb = new myBtn(pa);
            // set the background of the JButton
            jb.setText(miResultSet.getString("name"));

            //DESDE AQUI EMPIEZAN MIS PROBLEMAS

            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            iterador++;

            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.weightx = 2.0;
            c.weighty = 2.0;
            c.ipadx = 930;
            //c.gridwidth = 3;
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            //c.insets = new Insets(0,5,0,5);
            c.gridx = iterador;
            c.gridy = 1;


            pnlClientes.add(jb, c);
            pnlClientes.revalidate();
            pnlClientes.repaint();

            c = new GridBagConstraints();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo no es que domine mucho este layout, pero pienso que deberías iterar `c.gridy = iterador;` en vez de `c.gridx = iterador;`, ya que `gridy` es la fila en cuestión y la que debería cambiar de valor, y `gridx` corresponde a la columna, y esa es la que debería mantenerse siempre fija a 0 o 1, si lo que quieres disponer los componentes verticalmente. También podrías hacer que compartieran la misma instancia 'constraints' los componentes.

Comment: Si bueno, Ya encontre solucion y tienes razon en lo de c.gridy = Iterador; Ya lo habia cambiado, Publicare mi solucion :)

Comment: Un saludo amigo. Veo que trabajas duro :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre solucion haciendo el JScrollPane y el plnClientes(Osea el contenedor de los JButtons) desde cero a codigo puro, Estaba utilizando el diseñador de NetBeans y al parecer me modificaba cada uno de los Paneles que se introducian a un ScrollPane, Me gustaria saber por que y como solucionar eso usando el NetBeans..

Lo que hize fue crear una clase individual de el JPanelClientes:

```
public class pnlClientes extends JPanel{



public pnlClientes() {

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    setBackground(Color.red);//Le agregue para ver el JPanel
    setVisible(true);

    JScrollPane pnlScroll = new JScrollPane();
    JPanel pnlClientes = new JPanel();
    setOpaque(false);

    pnlScroll.setViewportView(pnlClientes);

    pnlScroll.add(pnlClientes);
    pnlScroll.getViewport().setOpaque(false);

}
```

}

Despues lo agregue a la clase principal:

```
public void cargarBtnCustomers(){
    try{
        Connection miConexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:customers_1.db");
    Statement miStatement = miConexion.createStatement();
    ResultSet miResultSet = miStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM customers_1");

    while(miResultSet.next()){
            //pnlIns.add(new JButton(new PersonAction(new Person(miResultSet.getString("name"), miResultSet.getString("identification")))).setBackground(Color.yellow));
            Person p = new Person(miResultSet.getString("name"),
            miResultSet.getString("ruc"), miResultSet.getString("repLegal"),
            miResultSet.getString("nombreContactoEmpresa"), miResultSet.getString("correoContactoEmpresa"),
            miResultSet.getString("numeroContacto"), miResultSet.getString("cedulaRepLegal"),
            miResultSet.getString("avisoOperaciones"), miResultSet.getString("nit"),
            miResultSet.getString("noContribuyenteMuniPa"), miResultSet.getString("contraMuniPa"),
            miResultSet.getString("obligacionFiscal"));
            // create a PersonAction with the recently created person as parameter
            PersonAction pa = new PersonAction(p);
            // create the JButton passing the PersonAction as parameter
            myBtn jb = new myBtn(pa);
            // set the background of the JButton
            jb.setText(miResultSet.getString("name"));




            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            iterador++;

            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.weightx = 2.0; 
            c.insets = new Insets(2, WIDTH, 2, HEIGHT);
            c.gridy = iterador; 
            pnlC.add(jb, c);
            pnlC.revalidate();
            pnlC.repaint();

            c = new GridBagConstraints();


        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Y listo, Asi quedo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier recomendacion diganmela :)

Answer (score 1):

**Actualizacion:**

Tomando prestado el código que proporcionas:

```
  //...

  while(miResultSet.next()){
      //pnlIns.add(new JButton(new PersonAction(new Person(miResultSet.getString("name"),   miResultSet.getString("identification")))).setBackground(Color.yellow));
      Person p = new Person(miResultSet.getString("name"),
      miResultSet.getString("ruc"), miResultSet.getString("repLegal"),
      miResultSet.getString("nombreContactoEmpresa"),
      miResultSet.getString("correoContactoEmpresa"), 
      miResultSet.getString("numeroContacto"),  
      miResultSet.getString("cedulaRepLegal"), 
      miResultSet.getString("avisoOperaciones"), 
      miResultSet.getString("nit"), 
      miResultSet.getString("noContribuyenteMuniPa"), 
      miResultSet.getString("contraMuniPa"), 
      miResultSet.getString("obligacionFiscal"));
      // create a PersonAction with the recently created person as parameter
      PersonAction pa = new PersonAction(p);
      // create the JButton passing the PersonAction as parameter
      myBtn jb = new myBtn(pa);
      // set the background of the JButton
      jb.setText(miResultSet.getString("name"));

      GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        iterador++;

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 2.0; //Toma el ancho total del contenedor
        c.gridy = iterador; //Agrega filas al GridBagLayout
        pnlClientes.add(jb, c);
  }
  //...
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No, De hecho asi es como lo tenia, Pero sucede que cuando solo hay un JButton hasta 4 ocupan todo el espacio, No solamente el Ancho si no que el Alto tambien, Por eso no es una opcion para mi.

Comment: Correcto, acabo de modificar la implementación usando de vuelta el `GridBagLayout` y algunos de sus _Constraints_

Comment: Acabo de pegar el codigo que pusiste, Y sigue igual, No entiendo por que, Y ya no se que hacer :(